# How many civilians do I need to save on terror missions?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

The terror missions I've been on have had either 16 or 18 civilians to save.

What are the thresholds for success and the corresponding differences in rewards in terms of number of civilians saved? Knowing this would help me better plan how many civilians I can accept as collateral damage.

Comment: Points -> Monthly Bonus, i think.

Comment: I think 14/18 is the fewest you can save while still getting a perfect rating. I imagine your rating determines how much panic decreases.

Comment: There's also a cheevo for getting the 'excellent' rating on all 3 categories for a terror mission.

Comment: One of the loading screen tips says that the amount of saved civilians affects panic reduction.

Comment: On normal level in one mission I've only saved 8 of 16 and still got "good" rating on civilians saved, and full panic reduction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a handy save, so I played around with killing some civilians.

75% or better gets you "Excellent." That's a mininmum of 14/18, or 12/16.
50% or better gets you "Good." That's 9/18, or 8/16.
Less than that gets you "Poor."
As far as I can tell, the only way to get "terrible" is to save no one, although I had already saved 3 civilians so I couldn't be sure. (You get this if you abort, too.)

"Good" and "Excellent" grant terror reduction across the continent, as well as in the target country. "Poor" only gets terror reduction in the target country. I'm not sure about "terrible."

Answer (score 1):

Not quite, sure, though I can make a guess. I've saved only 6 of 18 and gotten a Poor rating, and 12 of 18 and received a Good rating. The thresholds for success are likely simply based on the proportion saved, though the developers may have gotten fancy and  changed this proportion based on the game's difficulty, types of enemies, type of stage in the campaign (bridge, gas station, town, etc), or any other similar factors.

I'd like to see some more data on this, for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Saving no civilian results in a mission failure and the country leaves the council immediately.  I was getting greedy on chitin plating and let em transform all civvies. Killed all aliens, but the country still left. So at least save one civvy when you are farming.